# structuring Javascript for sharepoint code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, best-practices, jsom

I have been reading many articles and going through many video tutorials, they explain almost all patterns from javascript (`Module pattern`, `Prototype pattern`, `Revealing Module pattern` and etc) with SharePoint, but if we have to set a standard for using them in our coding, which one is suitable and easy to maintain for in terms of SharePoint, irrespective of what approach I use (`JSOM` or `REST`) for my CRUD operations. It would be helpful if someone can point me to link or articles or piece of code where I can understand and evaluate this, Or please share what standards you use when it comes to coding for SharePoint using JS.